# Insert variable value as element in array

Tags: bash, variable, array

If I have a variable that has a value stored and I want to place that value into an array using the name of the variable, how would I do this?

e.g.:

```
variable="Hello there"
array[0]=$variable
```

does not make array[0] equal to "Hello there"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly you invoked the _split+glob_ operator with `cmd ${array[0]}` or `cmd ${array[@]}`. That should be `cmd "${array[0]}"` or `cmd "${array[@]}"`, like `printf '<%s>\n' "${array[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

The array assignment is correct, you should check the printing part.

```
variable="Hello there"
array[0]=$variable
echo "${array[0]}"
```

output

```
Hello there
```